# Spring Security 5 OAuth2 client password grant type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have 2 applications:

1. Spring Application 1 is client and resource server.
2. Spring Application 2 is authorization server.

User will be able to login in Application 1 and access its resources.
And I want to implement the following flow:

User enter his credentials in login form -> Application 1 will get token from Application 2 using user credentials and its `clientId` with password grant type  -> Access resources of Application 1 with token.

The question is if Spring Security 5 supports password grant type for client? I found all rest grant types, but not password in Spring Security 5 implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Security 5.1.x doesn't support it, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client):

> **6.6 OAuth 2.0 Client**
>
> The OAuth 2.0 Client features provide support for the Client role as defined in the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework.
>
> The following main features are available:
>
> - Authorization Code Grant
> - Client Credentials Grant
> - `WebClient` extension for Servlet Environments (for making protected resource requests)
>
> `HttpSecurity.oauth2Client()` provides a number of configuration options for customizing OAuth 2.0 Client.

However, you could use Spring Security OAuth2, see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> **Accessing Protected Resources**
>
> As a general rule, a web application should not use password grants, so avoid using `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` if you can in favour of `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails`. If you desparately need password grants to work from a Java client, then use the same mechanism to configure your `OAuth2RestTemplate` and add the credentials to the AccessTokenRequest (which is a Map and is ephemeral) not the `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` (which is shared between all access tokens).

Or you could update to Spring Security 5.2.x, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client):

> **11.2 OAuth 2.0 Client**
>
> The OAuth 2.0 Client features provide support for the Client role as defined in the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework.
>
> At a high-level, the core features available are:
>
> **Authorization Grant support**
>
> - Authorization Code
> - Refresh Token
> - Client Credentials
> - Resource Owner Password Credentials

Comment: Spring security 5.2 supports it now

Comment: @JanZyka Thank you. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to execute the password flow in the latest version of spring security here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383562/spring-security-5-2-password-flow