# Resource Owner Password Credentials with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a legacy desktop application that communicates with a Spring Boot server (latest version `2.2.2.RELEASE`). I'm using OAuth2 for authentication (provided by `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`). I want to avoid changing the client because is a legacy application. It is capable of collecting the credentials and start the session via HTTP Basic Authentication, and then keep the cookies for the session in the following requests.

Given this scenario, I think best option is to make use the OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant. With this, we can exchange the collected credentials by the OAuth2 Tokens. We have two options:

**Option 1:**

Modify the client application to use the access tokens via the Authorization header. This will require to make an initial call to the Authorization Provider to exchange the collected credentials by the tokens.

**Option 2:**

Keep using the Spring session and store the information about the OAuth client in the server.

I found this project ALMOST does that: https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-5-2-migrate. It has a client (`messaging-client-password`) defined with `authorization-grant-type: password` which will activate the OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant in Spring Boot.

It creates an OAuth2 client and stores its information in the session, then Spring is able to use that client in further requests. The problem with this project is it seems to only work as when the OAuth client is used to make HTTP requests (e. g. an endpoint that makes a call to another service) and not provide authentication to the controller. You can find more information about this in here:

- [Spring Security 5.2 Password Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59442575/382877)
- Github related issues: [link1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7715), [link2](https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-5-2-migrate/issues/2), [link3](https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-5-2-migrate/issues/3)
- [Exception thrown when we try to use the password client as authentication](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/d3b7a47ef81960d9400134c5ed0b90ea253ca3a2/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java#L140)

The natural idea to overcome this is to implement a proxy and use the OAuth2 client in the requests. Well, Spring already offers a proxy solution, the Spring Cloud Gateway. But I don't know to accomplish that with this setup.

Any insights? Am I thinking correctly or should I follow a different approach?

Comment: https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-5-2-migrate/issues/3#issuecomment-571808154